# How to make Wxpython NewWindow appear to the Top

Tags: python, wxpython

When right key pressed down,  Popup Menu for 'edit' or 'delete' listctrl Item
If user selected 'edit', create a new window for editing
But the new window appear bottom of the old main window,
I know it may because i using wx.CallAfter(self.PopupMenu, MyPopupMenu(self, item), self.position)
But if i don't use wx.Callafter,
when i select a list item , 
Press right mouse key, choose the 'delete' menu,
A error dialog will appear " can not retrive information from list item XXX".
 how to make the new Window top and active? 
 Thank You

---

```
import wx


DATA = {
0 : (u"Test2", "123456", ),
1 : (u"Test", "123456",),
2 : (u"doe", "156789", ),
3 : (u"John", "13455", )
}


class MyApp(wx.App):

    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None)
        frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.NewId(), size=(500, -1))
        wx.Frame.CenterOnScreen(self)
        self.panel = MyPanel(self)


class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.list = MyListCtrl(self,3)
        self.add_button = wx.Button(self, label="add")
        h_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        h_sizer.Add(self.add_button, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        v_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        v_sizer.Add(h_sizer, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        v_sizer.Add(self.list, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND, border=5)
        self.SetSizer(v_sizer)
        self.add_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.onAdd)

    def onAdd(self, event):
        self.new_w = NewWindow(self)
        self.new_w.Show()


class MyPopupMenu(wx.Menu):

    def __init__(self,parent, item):
        super(MyPopupMenu,self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.item = item
        menuEdit = wx.MenuItem(self,wx.NewId(), 'edit %s' % item[0])
        self.AppendItem(menuEdit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onEdit, menuEdit)
        menuDel = wx.MenuItem(self,wx.NewId(), 'delete %s' % item[0])
        self.AppendItem(menuDel)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnDelete, menuDel)

    def onEdit(self,e):
        self.parent.parent.edit_w = NewWindow(self.parent.parent)
        self.parent.parent.edit_w.Show()

    def OnDelete(self,e):
        self.parent.DeleteAllItems()

class MyListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, columns):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.parent = parent
        self.R_MOUSE = 0
        self.InsertColumn(0, "name")
        self.InsertColumn(1, "phone")
        self.InsertColumn(2, "address")
        self.SetColumnWidth(0, 200)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.OnSelect)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN, self.OnRightDown)
        self.itemDataMap = {}
        self.refresh_list()


    def refresh_list(self):
        self.DeleteAllItems()
        for entry in DATA.items():
            self.Append(entry[1])
            self.SetItemData(entry[0],entry[0])

    def OnRightDown(self, event):
        self.R_MOUSE = 1
        self.position = event.GetPosition()
        event.Skip()

    def OnSelect(self, event):
        index = event.GetIndex()
        item = []
        for i in range(3):
            item.append(self.GetItem(itemId=index, col=i).GetText())
        self.SetItemState(index, 0, wx.LIST_STATE_SELECTED)
        self.SetItemBackgroundColour(index, wx.Colour(255,255,0))
        if self.R_MOUSE:
            self.R_MOUSE = 0
            self.PopupMenu(MyPopupMenu(self, item), self.position)


class NewWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, size=(400,250), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        self.parent = parent
        self.CenterOnParent()
        panel = wx.Panel(self)


    def onClick(self,event):
        self.Close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the flag **wx.STAY_ON_TOP**

try this:

```
class NewWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, size=(400,250), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE| wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
Using flag wx.STAY_ON_TOP can make it  top but not active(focused).
How to make it focused?

Comment: Tried with menu = MyPopupMenu(self, item),
            self.PopupMenu(menu) to replace your wx.CallAfter,  didn't see any error you mentioned

Comment: If You don't use wx.CallAfter,  there will be some error because you can't delete item in the SELECTED even handler